# Create DAX to count number of cases per month in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In my dataset I have the case number, repair arrived date and repair finished date.

I want to create 2 different measures in order to count how many cases arrived per month and how many cases finished per month. I used the following measure to calculate the number of cases that arrived per month, but I see the same number of cases for all the months. Could anyone help me?  Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqsHO.png)

```
Monthly cases arrived = VAR StartDate = DATE(2022,11,1) VAR EndDate = DATE(2023,5,8) return CALCULATE(COUNT('All cases'[Case Number]), 'All cases'[Repair Arrived Date]>= StartDate, 'All cases'[Repair Arrived Date]<= EndDate, DATESBETWEEN('Date'[Date], StartDate, EndDate))
```

I try to count the number of cases arrived and finished per month

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)